# XSLT: how to get value from <Node id=$variable>

Tags: xml, xslt

So I want to get a subnode value from a node with an id parameter stored in $variable.

XML code pattern:

```
<DocumentVersion id="not_relevant">
    <Specification id="id_2000_2">
        <Terminal id="not_relevant">
            <Name>Name1</Name>
            <Size>Size1</Size>
        </Terminal>
    </Specification>
    <Specification id="id_2000_0">
        <Node id="not_relevant">
            <Subnode id="not_relevant">
                <SubnodeNumber>1</SubnodeNumber>
                <SubnodeSpecification>id_2000_2</SubnodeSpecification>
            </Subnode>
            <Subnode id="not_relevant">
                <SubnodeNumber>2</SubnodeNumber>
                <SubnodeSpecification>id_2000_3</SubnodeSpecification>
            </Subnode>
            <Subnode id="not_relevant">
                <SubnodeNumber>1</SubnodeNumber>
                <SubnodeSpecification>id_2000_2</SubnodeSpecification>
            </Subnode>
        </Node>
    </Specification>
    <Specification id="id_2000_3">
        <Terminal id="not_relevant">
            <Name>Name2</Name>
            <Size>Size2</Size>
        </Terminal>
    </Specification>
</DocumentVersion>
```

XSLT code (html table tags included but you get the point):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.1">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="//Subnode[@id]">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SubnodeNumber"/>
                </td>
                <xsl:variable name="specid" select="SubnodeSpecification"/>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$specid"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Specification[@id=$specid]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//Size"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Specification[@id=$specid]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//Name"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Take a closer look at lines 2 in both outputs. Currently I always get Size1 and Name1. $specid contains correct id but somehow XSLT sees only values for id_2000_2.

Current output:

```
<SubnodeNumber>      $specid             <Size>            <Name>
    1                id_2000_2            Size1            Name1
    2                id_2000_3            Size1            Name1
    3                id_2000_2            Size1            Name1
```

Desired output:

```
<SubnodeNumber>      $specid             <Size>            <Name>
    1                id_2000_2            Size1            Name1
    2                id_2000_3            Size2            Name2
    3                id_2000_2            Size1            Name1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data is not well formed, it misses two closing tags.

Also, it seems inconsistent, you have id_2000_2 twice, but no id_2000_3 in your data.

Assuming these issues are fixed, you can fix your stylesheet by replacing

```
 <xsl:value-of select="//Name"></xsl:value-of>
```

with

```
 <xsl:value-of select=".//Name"></xsl:value-of>
```

or

```
 <xsl:value-of select="Terminal/Name"></xsl:value-of>
```

(select starting from the current context node in your for-each).

in order to select the Name element from the current content.

Full XML:

```
<DocumentVersion id="not_relevant">
<Specification id="id_2000_2">
    <Terminal id="not_relevant">
        <Name>Name1</Name>
        <Size>Size1</Size>
    </Terminal>
</Specification>
<Specification id="id_2000_0">
    <Node id="not_relevant">
        <Subnode id="not_relevant">
            <SubnodeNumber>1</SubnodeNumber>
            <SubnodeSpecification>id_2000_2</SubnodeSpecification>
        </Subnode>
        <Subnode id="not_relevant">
            <SubnodeNumber>2</SubnodeNumber>
            <SubnodeSpecification>id_2000_3</SubnodeSpecification>
        </Subnode>
        <Subnode id="not_relevant">
            <SubnodeNumber>1</SubnodeNumber>
            <SubnodeSpecification>id_2000_2</SubnodeSpecification>
        </Subnode>
    </Node> <!-- Changed -->
</Specification>
<Specification id="id_2000_3"> <!-- Changed -->
    <Terminal id="not_relevant">
        <Name>Name2</Name>
        <Size>Size2</Size>
    </Terminal>
</Specification>
```

Full XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.1">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Subnode[@id]">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SubnodeNumber"/>
                </td>
                <xsl:variable name="specid" select="SubnodeSpecification"/>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$specid"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Specification[@id=$specid]">
                        <xsl:value-of select=".//Size"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Specification[@id=$specid]">
                        <xsl:value-of select=".//Name"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>id_2000_2</td>
    <td>Size1</td>
    <td>Name1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>id_2000_3</td>
    <td>Size2</td>
    <td>Name2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>id_2000_2</td>
    <td>Size1</td>
    <td>Name1</td>
 </tr>
```